# How can I dynamically add an attribute to a body element in a GSP page

Tags: grails, gsp

In Grails 2.3.7, is there a way to use an expression in a GSP page to add an attribute to a body element?  In the code below, the expression in the `p` element works, but the same expression in the `body` element causes a error: **Expecting '=' after attribute name (${raw('this="that"')}).**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
   <body ${raw('this="that"')}>
        <p ${raw('this="that"')}>Hello!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to do this in a layout and pick up the corresponding attribute from the original page with `pageProperty`, but the same error occurs on the `body` element in the page layout as well.

Replacing an attribute value does work in a `body` element like this:

```
<body this="${that}">
```

but this won't work because I do not want the attribute to appear at all if it has no value.

Comment: what abut adding it using javascript or jquery ... have u tried that

Answer (score 3):

the problem is, that the body tag is replaced by the `<g:layoutBody />` tag and therefore could not be set like this.

One solution is to use  to set different stuff in the sitemesh layout.
An example of this is shown [here](http://blog.bloidonia.com/post/60939849475/changing-body-class-in-grails):

```
<html>
<head>
    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>
<body class="${pageProperty( name:'body.class' )}">
    <g:layoutBody/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've clarified a bit.  This error occurs in `body` elements in either plain pages or in sitemesh layouts.  I need to make sure the attribute doesn't appear *at all* when it has no value, so a solution like yours won't work.